# cakephp: remove stars in all choices in a radio button

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a radio button in my form using the following code

```
echo $form->input('Users.vote', array(
 'type' => 'radio',
 'label' => array('text' => __("form_vote", "true"), 'class' => 'vote'),
 'options' => array('1' => 'a', '2' => 'b', '3' => 'c' ),
));
```

This is my model validation for vote

```
  'vote' => array(
        'rule' => 'inList', array(1,2,3), 
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'error_vote'
    )
```

Problem is that it adds a * right next to the a, b and c choices. Here is a screengrab on what it looks like with the stars on all three choices.  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/radiojpg.jpg/
I'd like the star to only be displayed on the label 'Vote'

Here is the html output

```
 <div class="input radio required"><fieldset><legend>Vote</legend><input type="hidden" value="" id="UserVote_" name="data[User][vote]">
 <input type="radio" value="1" id="UserVote1" name="data[User][vote]">
 <label for="UserVote1">a<span class="red">*</span></label>
 <input type="radio" value="2" id="UserVote2" name="data[User][vote]">
 <label for="UserVote2">b<span class="red">*</span></label>
 <input type="radio" value="3" id="UsertVote3" name="data[User][vote]">
 <label for="Vote3">c<span class="red">*</span></label></fieldset></div>
```

Comment: This is actually caused by CSS - from the default Cake stylesheet. 
`form .required label:after { color: #e32; content: '*'; display:inline; }`  If you can post the HTML output, it will be easy to identify what classes/CSS need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an attribute called legend with a name to group all radio

```
echo $form->input('Users.vote', array(
 'type' => 'radio',
 'legend' => 'Vote*',
 'class' => 'vote',
 'options' => array('1' => 'a', '2' => 'b', '3' => 'c' ),
));
```

Comment: Perfect!, I did the test in cakephp 2.0 but also works for 1.3

Answer (score 3):

I don't prefer using legends so I added a label before the radio list:

`<?php echo $this->Form->label('radioname', __('Label:', true), 'required'); ?>`

Then adjusted the css for the new label and the radio button labels:

```
label.required:after {
  color: #e32;
  content: '*';
  display:inline;
}

.radio label{
  font-weight:normal;
}
.radio label:after{
  display:none !important;
}
```