# how to get rid of those red stars on radio button labels

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I just wondering how to get rid of those annoying star near on radio button's label and move them just to the label.

```
  echo $this->Form->input('experience',array('type'=>'radio', 'options'=> array('1'=>'1','2'=>'2','3'=>'3','4'=>'4','5'=>'5')));
```

====================================================
Expected output:

Experience*:

1 2 3 4 5

=====================================================

Output I am getting:

Experience:

1* 2* 3* 4* 5*

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381495/cakephp-remove-stars-in-all-choices-in-a-radio-button).

Comment: but its not a red star I guess. I would like it to be displayed like other type of input field label+a red star indicates mandatory

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp uses options as value => label pairs, so your options should look like

`... 'options' => array('1' => '1*', '2' => '2*', etc etc) ...`